# Can the derivative of a real function be imaginary?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

Suppose $f$ is a real function (e.g. mapping $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$). Is it possible for its derivative (i.e. $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$) to be imaginary?

Comment: On the other hand complex-differentiable (aka holomorphic) functions $f\colon\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ can have a purely real derivative. However, by some well-known theorems, $f'$ being again complex-differentiable and purely real implies $f'$ being constant. Hence, by integration $f$ must have been a linear function of the form $f(z) = cz + w$ for $c \in \mathbb{R}$, $w \in \mathbb{C}$. So overall, the complex-differentiable functions $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ with purely real derivative are *exactly* the linear functions.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No. The derivative is defined as
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
This is a limit of real numbers, hence if it exists it is real.

Answer (score 5):

No, it cannot. Since $f'(x_0)=\lim_{x\to x_0}\dfrac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$ and since the limit at a point of a real function is (if it exists) a real number, $f'(x_0)\in\mathbb R$.